# Return value changing between functions

Tags: java, parsing, recursion, return, abstract-syntax-tree

I am making a recursive decent parser with this grammar.

```
     Expr -> Term ( '+' | '-' ) Expr | Term

     Term -> Number ( '*' | '/' ) Term | Number

   Number -> any valid Java double
```

And My getTerm Method looks like this.

```
private static BTree getTerm(Tokenizer tokens)
 {
       String tokenHold = "";
       BTree result = new BTree(getNumber(tokens).getElement()); 
       System.out.println("VALUE of result : " + result.toString());
       while(tokens.hasToken() && ("*/".indexOf(tokens.peekToken()) != -1)){

       BTree newTree = null;
       boolean isMulti = false; 
       boolean isDiv = false;
       if(tokens.peekToken().equals("*")){
           isMulti = true;
           }
       if(tokens.peekToken().equals("/")){
           isDiv = true;
           }

       if(isMulti) {
           newTree = new BTree( "*" );
           }
       else if(isDiv){
           newTree = new BTree( "/" );
       }
       tokenHold = tokens.nextToken();
       newTree.addLeftTree(result);
       newTree.addRightTree(getTerm(tokens));

       result = newTree;

   }
   System.out.println("Expression of result : " + result.toString());
   return result;
```

}

It returns to the getExpr method which looks like

```
 private static BTree getExpr(Tokenizer tokens)
 {
       String tokenHold = "";

       BTree result = new BTree(getTerm(tokens).getElement());//consumes term
       System.out.println("Expression of result in getExpr: " + result.toString());
       while(tokens.hasToken() && ("+-".indexOf(tokens.peekToken()) != -1)){
       BTree newTree = null;
       boolean isAdd =  false;
       boolean isSub = false;

       if(tokens.peekToken().equals("+")){isAdd = true;}
       if(tokens.peekToken().equals("-")){isSub = true;}
       if(isAdd){ newTree = new BTree( "+" );}
       else if(isSub){ newTree = new BTree( "-" );}
       tokenHold = tokens.nextToken();
       newTree.addRightTree(result);

       newTree.addLeftTree(getTerm(tokens));  // old tree on the right
       result = newTree;
   }

   return result;
}
```

Constructors for the BTree

```
public BTree(String element)
 {
  this.element = element;
  left  = null;
  right = null;
 }

 public BTree(String element, BTree left, BTree right)
 {
  this.element = element;
  this.left  = left;
  this.right = right;
 }
```

When I input this syntax 4 / 2 / 2 .  The getTerm Method has the correct values being returned " (/ 4 (/ 2 2)) " but the getExpr only see's "/". I have sat and tried to figure out my issue but I think I might have a fundamental miss understanding of how these two methods are passing arguments. I also have a feeling it is because of the recursion.  I will answer this question myself if I figure it out myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using loops along with recursion just looks painful.

Comment: your Right I think I'm going to try to implement with an if statement. I'll update an answer when I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I finally figured it out.

in my getExpr method I was using a constructor that I didn't include in the original question for the Binary Tree it looks like this

```
public BTree(String element)
 {
  this.element = element;
  left  = null;
  right = null;
 }
```

I should have been using the constructor that had both the left and right child of the tree. This constructor looks like this.

```
public BTree(String element, BTree left, BTree right)
 {
  this.element = element;
  this.left  = left;
  this.right = right;
 }
```

Because I was not using the correct constructor when passing this value from the getTerm method to getExpr method I lost some of the information and thus was only getting the root.  I am new to binary  tree's / Recursion / AST and sometimes forget the BIG picture when working with these tools.